# PHP How to loop randomly through an array of placeholders

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have a search input in my wordpress site, which I want to display different placeholdes each time the page been refreshed. So I will have an array of the different values, the function that will loop randomly through the array, and I think my problem is with the result. I'm using a plugin for the search input, so to define for example that the placeholder would say 'hello', I need to do:

```
$item['textinput']= "hello";
```

So I need the result to be:

```
$item['textinput']= $placeholders;
```

I am adding the whole code:

```
$placeholders = array("yo i hio", "and him", "nayo jones");


 function randominputs($input){

    $i=1;
     while($i<=20){
     $randNum =  rand(1,100);

  if($input==$i){

     $item['textinput']= $placeholders; 
   }

    $i++;
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding the sizeof() call to your code.

For example if I wanted to call a random result from an array you could try...

```
       $arr = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");

       $len = sizeof($arr) - 1; // account for the 0 position

       $rand = rand(0,$len);

       echo $arr[$rand];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `array_rand`:

```
$placeholder = $placeholders[array_rand($placeholders)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like:

```
$placeholders = array("yo i hio", "and him", "nayo jones");

$randomPlaceholder = array_rand($placeholders);
$item["textinput"] = $randomPlaceholder[0];
```